# how to calculate infimum of Augmented Lagrangian?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

should any body explain that how do we calculate these step?
\begin{align*}
L(x,y) &= f(x) + y^T(Ax-b)\\
g(y) &= \inf_x \, L(x,y) \\
&= \inf_x \, f(x) - \langle -A^Ty, x \rangle - \langle y, b \rangle \\
&= - \sup_x \, \langle -A^Ty, x \rangle - f(x) + \langle y, b \rangle \\
&= - f^*(-A^T y) - \langle y, b \rangle.
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}how\ does\ A\ become\ A^T\ ?\end{align*}

especially step 3, 4,and 5. kindly explain how do i derive each step in details?

thanks

Comment: Since the quantities are real, $$\langle y, A x \rangle = y^T(Ax)=y^TAx=(y^TAx)^T=x^TA^Ty=x^T(A^Ty) = \langle x, A^T y \rangle$$

Comment: thank you Michael, i got little bit. would you explain step 3, 4 and 5? how do they actually derive?